# User authentication timing out before expiry config in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, session, authentication, symfony-1.4

I've got the user authentication timeout set beyond the default 30 mins but I'm still finding that the user is being timedout. This is creating issues with csrf protected forms.

factories.yml

```
storage:
  class: sfSessionStorage
  param:
    session_cookie_lifetime: 604800
    session_cookie_httponly: true

user:
  class: myUser
  param:
    timeout: 604800
```

The gc.session_timeout is set to the same value
It works fine on my local, it is only on production that there are problems. Any ideas as to what is causing the early timeout? If I changed to `sfPDOSessionStorage` is this likely to make a difference?

Comment: Did you try without the session_cookie_lifetime, because this should not be needed. On my sf project, I only use the 'user':'param':'timeout' config and it works ... Oh and also verify that there is no other .yml file that is overriding you config. global config vs app config !

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your User class with a new attribute authenticationExpiration :

```
`
class CustomUser extends User
{
    protected $authenticationExpiration;

    public function setAuthenticationExpiration( $timestamp)
    {
        $this->authenticationExpiration = $timestamp;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthenticationExpiration()
    {
        return $this->authenticationExpiration;
    }
}`
```

You can customize the UserProvider method "refereshUser" like this :

`

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
    if (!$this->supportsClass(get_class($user))) {
       throw new UnsupportedUserException('usuported class');
    }

    // durée
    if( time() > $user->getAuthenticationExpiration() ){
        throw new AutoLoginTokenNotFoundException('Login failed');
    }
    else {
        return $user;
    }
}
```

`

And add at the end of your User Provider service method "loadUserByUsername($username)" :

`

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
     // ...
     $user = new CustomUser($username, $data); 
     $user->setAuthenticationExpiration( time() + 3600);
     return $user ;
}
```

`